# Gnome 3.8 icons on the desktop (Nautilus managed) are on the wrong monitor

Tags: gnome, desktop, icons, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm running GNOME 3.8 with a multi-monitor setup. In Gnome 3, it's possible to get the icons in `~/Desktop` back on one's desktop by changing a setting in `gnome-tweak-tool`:

> http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GNOME/3.8-upgrade-guide#Icons_on_the_desktop

This gets Nautilus to manage the desktop and worked fine on GNOME 3.6. However, in GNOME 3.8 the icons are not displaying on the primary monitor anymore. Moreover, they are extending off the screen (even after 'Organize Desktop By Name') because it seems Nautilus thinks it is on the (bigger) primary monitor but is outputting to a small secondary monitor.

Is there any way to change the monitor that the icons are being displayed on?